How do I fix my .onChange(of:perform) to avoid Xcode giving me a deprecation warning?
I am apptemting to learn SwiftUI, Swift, and Xcode for macOS.  The code below works but I'd like to have no warnings.  The complete warning is:

'onChange(of:perform:)' was deprecated in macOS 14.0: Use onChange with a two or zero parameter action closure instead.

but I cannot interpret it.  I'm using macOS 15
This works but the warning is generated.
.onChange(of: thisImageIndex) { newValue in
    // Update currentDatum when the index changes
    if newValue >= 0 && newValue < imageList.count {
        currentDatum = imageList[newValue]
        imageCaption = currentDatum!.displayName
    }
}


Try changing it to: .onChange(of: thisImageIndex) { oldValue, newValue in

To remove warning, you need to update your code to add old value
.onChange(of: thisImageIndex) { oldValue, newValue in
    // Update currentDatum when the index changes
    if newValue >= 0 && newValue < imageList.count {
        currentDatum = imageList[newValue]
        imageCaption = currentDatum!.displayName
    }
}


I figured it out for my purpose!  I guess I'm getting better at this!

.onChange(of: thisImageIndex) {
    if thisImageIndex >= 0 && thisImageIndex < imageList.count {
      currentDatum = imageList[thisImageIndex]
      imageCaption = currentDatum!.displayName
  }
}


